# problems with changing of xdata of lines in matplotlib.axes

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

everybody.

I want to change xdata of a Line2D in matplotlib, but I have problem that when I change xdata of one line xdata from the other line changes too.

For example we have some data[i][n] and some constant k

```
fig = Figure((5.0, 4.0), dpi=self.dpi)
axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
for i in range(1,len(data)):
    axes.plot(data[0],data[i])
lines=axes.get_lines()
for j in range (0,len(lines)):
    data = lines[j].get_xdata()
    for x in range (0,len(data)):
        data[x]=data[x]+k
    lines[j].set_xdata(data)
```

In the end you would get that xdata for every line had been increased for len(lines)*k.
Looks like xdata for every line shares same pointer. Is it really possible for different objects of Line2D. Or maybe it is some kind of bug?

Comment: Perhaps if you make copies of the x data you put into your call to `plot`, e.g., `axes.plot(data[0][:], data[i])`.

Comment: Tried that, it doesn't work. Anyway, axes.plot() should make copies, IMHO.

Comment: Interesting thing! Used "data=data+k" instead of "for x in range (0,len(lines)): data[x]=data[x]+k" and it works right. Who can explain that?